# Responsive form using bootstrap css

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

https://plnkr.co/edit/vWR7kK9MQw4nyciRt1Bj?p=preview

I have uploaded my code in plunker. Till media screen size 768px,1260px form is responsive.I need to have atleast three input fields per row at media screen level 480px-760px , but All I get is only one field per row. After that at media screen at minimum size 480px per row only one field is coming. Need assistance.

I tried adjusting width of fields.
For your reference Css and Html code as follows:

HTML :

```
<form name="tForm" role="form" data-ng-init="resp()">
  <div class="row newRow">
    <div class="form-group fields col-sm-2" ng-class="{'has-error': (tForm.fname.$dirty || tForm.$submitted) && tForm.fname.$invalid }">
      <label for="fname">FIRST NAME *</label>
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="fname" class="form-control1 col-sm-2" autocomplete="off" ng-required="true" ng-model="firstName" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/" ng-minlength=1/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group fields col-sm-2">
      <label>LAST NAME *</label>
      <input type="text" name="lname" class="form-control1" autocomplete="off" ng-required="true" ng-model="lastName" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group fields col-sm-2">
      <label>GENDER *</label>
      <br>
      <select name="gender" class="form-control1 drop" required ng-model="gender" placeholder="select">
        <option value='' disabled selected>Select</option>
        <option value="male">Male</option>
        <option value="female">Female</option>
        <option value="transpant">Transgender</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group fields col-sm-2">
      <label>DOB</label>

      <div class="form-group">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  .newrow {
    width: 100;
  }
  .firstfields {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 5px;
  }
  .drop2 {
    padding: 6px;
    padding-right: 3em;
    border: none;
    color: black;
    width: 85%;
  }
  .fields {
    border: 1px #A9A9A9 solid;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 1em;
    height: 75px;
    color: #A9A9A9;
    font-size: 11px;
  }
  input[type=text] {
    width: 65%;
    margin: 8px 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    transition: 0.5s;
    outline: none;
  }
  input[type=email] {
    width: 65%;
    margin: 8px 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    transition: 0.5s;
    outline: none;
  }
  input[type=email]:focus {
    border: 3px solid #fff;
  }
  .drop {
    width: 160px;
  }
  .drop select:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 3pt 2pt #fff!important;
  }
  .drop1 {
    width: 85%;
    padding: 6px;
    padding-right: 6em;
    border: none;
    color: black;
  }
  input[type=text]:focus {
    border: 3px solid #fff;
  }
  .newpagebody {
    background-size: auto;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please make your requirements clear by being more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use col-ms - (mid-small) between 480 and 768

And if u want 3, you should do `class="col-ms-4"` and do `class="row"` around those 3 divs you want in same row

Answer (score 1):

For targeting specific screen size below `768px` width, you can use `col-xs-*` class.

So, to have 3 input fields per row, you should add `col-xs-4` class to the form-group.

like  -
 `class="form-group fields col-xs-4 col-sm-2"`

Additionally, for below `768px` resolution you need to remove given additional `width` to the `.fields` as well as `.newrow` class.

as below -

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px)
.newrow {
   /*  width: 100; */   /* removed */
}

@media screen and (min-width: 480px)
.fields {
    border: 1px #A9A9A9 solid;
    /* width: 200px; */   /* removed */
    margin: 0em;         /* editied - to avoid impact on responsiveness */
    height: 75px;
    color: #A9A9A9;
    font-size: 11px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 480px)
input[type=text] {
    width: 100%;              /* edited */
    /* padding: 12px 20px; */ /* removed */
    margin: 8px 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    transition: 0.5s;
    outline: none;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 480px)
.drop {
    width: 100%;  /* edited */
}
```

For more information about responsive grid system read   - `http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp`